# differentiate $y=\sin(xy)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

so I am using chain rule to differentiate this and get down to 
$ \cos(xy) \times \left( x \frac{dy}{dx} + y \right)$
 and then I don't know what to do next. The book says the answer is 
$\frac{ y\cos(xy)}{1-x\cos(xy)}$, but I am not sure how they get that. If anyone can do a step by step of this problem, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}[y] = \frac{d}{dx}[\sin(xy)]$

chain rule on right gives

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(xy)\frac{d}{dx}[xy]$

product rule on right gives

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(xy)(y + x\frac{dy}{dx}) = y\cos(xy) + x\cos(xy)\frac{dy}{dx}$

putting dy/dx terms on same side

$\frac{dy}{dx} - x\cos(xy)\frac{dy}{dx} = y\cos(xy)$

factor out a common factor of dy/dx

$\frac{dy}{dx}(1-x\cos(xy)) = y\cos(xy)$

divide both sides by 1-xcos(xy)

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y\cos(xy)}{1-x\cos(xy)}$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help if you wrote out the entire equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos   xy\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y\right)$$

From here, it's algebra.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\left(1-x\cos   xy\right)=y\cos   xy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y\cos   xy}{1-x\cos   xy}$$